# HashMap with weak values

Tags: java, android, hashmap, weak-references

I'm implementing a cache for Objects stored persistently. The idea is:

- Method `getObjectFromPersistence(long id);  ///Takes about 3 seconds`
- Method `getObjectFromCache(long id)  //Instantly`

And have a method: `getObject(long id)` with the following pseudocode:

```
synchronized(this){
    CustomObject result= getObjectFromCache(id)
    if (result==null){
       result=getObjectFromPersistence(id);
       addToCache(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I need to allow the CustomObject to be collected by the garbage collector. Until now I was using an `HashMap<Long,WeakReference<CustomObject>` for the implementation. The problem is that over the time the HashMap becomes filled of empty `WeakReferences`.

I've checked [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) but there the keys are weak  (and the values are still strong references) so having the longs with WeakReferences have no sense.

Whats the best solution for solving this problem? Is there some "inverse WeakHashMap" or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the cache functionality found in the Google Guava library? I think it may contain some of the funcionality you are looking for. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Reference-based_Eviction

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`MapMaker`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) for this:

```
ConcurrentMap<Long, CustomObject> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .weakValues()
   .makeMap();
```

You can even include the computation part by replacing `makeMap()` with this:

```
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Long, CustomObject>() {
         public CustomObject apply(Long id) {
           return getObjectFromPersistence(id);
         }
       });
```

Since what you are writing looks a lot like a cache, the newer, more specialized [`Cache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) (built via a [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html)) might be even more relevant to you. It doesn't implement the `Map` interface directly, but provides even more controls that you might want for a cache.

You can refer to [this](http://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache) for a detailed how to work for CacheBuilder and here is an example for fast access:

```
LoadingCache<Integer, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(100)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Integer, String>() {
           @Override
           public String load(Integer id) throws Exception {
               return "value";
           }
       }
   );
```

Answer (score 6):

A `WeakReference` is added to its [`ReferenceQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) supplied at the construction time when its reference is collected.

You could `poll` the `ReferenceQueue` whenever you access the cache, and hold a `HashMap<WeakReference<CustomObject>,Long>` to know which entry to remove if a reference is found in the queue.

Alternatively, if the cache is not frequently used, you can [watch the queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html#remove()) in a separate thread.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [`android.util.LruCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) (its a SDK11 class but it's also in the compatibility package as [`android.support.v4.util.LruCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html)). It does not implement `java.util.Map` but works like a Map and you can define how much memory will it take and it will flush old (unused cached objects by itself).

Answer (score 2):

You could start a "cleanup" - Thread every once in a while. Perhaps if your map  size exceeds a threshold but at most every 5 minutes .... something like that.

Keep the cleanup cycles short to not block the main functionality.

Comment: or you could clean x entries on each request. Easier to implement and doesn't stop the world.

Comment: Excellent , Jan. That should do the job with low complexity.

Comment: Good idea, @JanDvorak. There's one drawback: infrequently accessed caches might still hold on to unused data for longer than expected. As long as the cache is used often, that's a perfectly fine strategy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also test WeakValueHashMap from jboss-common http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/util/collection/WeakValueHashMap.java.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option (if a dependency on Guava is undesirable) would be to use a custom subclass of WeakReference that remembers its ID, so that your cleanup thread can remove the weak values during cleanup of the WeakReferences.

The implementation of the weak reference, with the necessary ReferenceQueue and cleanup thread would look something like this:

```
class CustomObjectAccess {

    private static final ReferenceQueue<CustomObject> releasedCustomObjects = 
                                                                  new ReferenceQueue<>();

    static {
        Thread cleanupThread = new Thread("CustomObject cleanup thread")                  
            while (true) {
                CustomObjectWeakReference freed = (CustomObjectWeakReference) 
                                CustomObjectWeakReference.releasedCustomObjects.remove();
                cache.remove(freed.id);
            }
        };
        cleanupThread.start();
    }

    private Map<CustomObjectID, CustomObjectWeakReference> cache;

    public CustomObject get(CustomObjectID id) {
        synchronized(this){
            CustomObject result= getFromCache(id);
            if (result==null) {
                result=getObjectFromPersistence(id);
                addToCache(result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private addToCache(CustomObject co) {
        cache.put(CustomObject.getID(), new CustomObjectWeakReference(co));
    }

    private getFromCache(CustomObjectID id) {
        WeakReference<CustomObject> weak = cache.get(id);
        if (weak != null) {
            return weak.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class CustomObjectWeakReference extends WeakReference<CustomObject> {

        private final CustomObjectID id;

        CustomObjectWeakReference(CustomObject co) {
            super(co, releasedCustomObjects);
            this.id = co.getID();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the need to store tagged weak objects and figured instead of using `WeakHashMap<String, T>`, I could just use `WeakHashMap<T, String>` instead.

This is Kotlin, but should apply to Java equally:

```
abstract class InstanceFactory<T> {
    @Volatile
    private var instances: MutableMap<T, String> = WeakHashMap<T, String>()

    protected fun getOrCreate(tag: String = SINGLETON, creator: () -> T): T =
        findByTag(tag)?.let {
            it
        } ?: synchronized(this) {
            findByTag(tag)?.let {
                it
            } ?: run {
                creator().also {
                    instances[it] = tag
                }
            }
        }

    private fun findByTag(tag: String): T? = instances.entries.find { it.value == tag }?.key

    companion object {
        const val SINGLETON = "singleton"
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
class Thing(private val dependency: Dep) { ... }

class ThingFactory(private val dependency: Dep) : InstanceFactory<Thing>() {

    createInstance(tag: String): Thing = getOrCreate(tag) { Thing(dependency) }

}
```

Simple singletons can be done like this:

```
object ThingFactory {
    getInstance(dependency: Dependency): Thing = getOrCreate { Thing(dependency) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [ReferenceMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ReferenceMap.html) in [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/collections/), this is a map implementation with hard keys and soft values (the opposite of WeakHashMap).